# VBA to delete sheets not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following function to work with several workbooks at once:

```
 Public Property Get SPATH() As String


SPATH = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

Function GETIMPORTFILE(Index As Long) As String

    Select Case Index

        Case 1: GETIMPORTFILE = "New Leave.xlsx"
        Case 2: GETIMPORTFILE = "Return To Work.xlsx"

    End Select

End Function
```

Then I worked on this loop to delete the sheet names from those sheets that are unnecessary.

```
Sub delete_extra_Sheets()

    Dim n As Long
    Dim strImportFile As String

    For n = 1 To 2 Step -1

        strImportFile = SPATH & GETIMPORTFILE(n)

        With Workbooks.Open(strImportFile)

            If n = "Segments" Or n = "Summary" Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    Sheets(n).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If

        End With

    Next n

End Sub
```

However, my code is not working. I do not get an error, or anywhere to debug. It just doesn't fire. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: re: `For n = 1 To 2 Step -1` Do you mean `For n = 1 To 2 Step 1` or `For n = 2 To 1 Step -1` ?

Comment: Also, n is going to be either 2 or 1. It's never going to be Segments or Summary.

Comment: As Jeeped tried to say,  the inner part of the for loop will not be executed, just debug the code by pressing F8 and you will see.

Comment: Dude, this code is wrong from A to Z. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to open two workbooks and then deleting two sheets by the names of "summary" and "Segments" on both books.

Comment: You have 3 good answers down there!

Comment: Thank you all, this was an education for. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for any loop

```
Sub delete_extra_Sheets()
    Dim n As Long

    For n = 1 To 2
        With Workbooks.Open(SPATH & GETIMPORTFILE(n))
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            On Error Resume Next 
            .Sheets("Segments").Delete
            .Sheets("Summary").Delete 
            On Error GoTo 0 
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `Step -1` for your loop.

Add new declaration of `ws` as we are creating another loop within your loop -- this one will loop through the worksheets within the workbook.

```
Sub delete_extra_Sheets()

    Dim n As Long, ws As Worksheet  '<-- New declaration
    Dim strImportFile As String

    For n = 1 To 2

        strImportFile = SPATH & GETIMPORTFILE(n)

        With Workbooks.Open(strImportFile)

            For Each ws In .Worksheets
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False

                Select Case ws.Name
                    Case "Segments", "Summary"
                        ws.Delete
                End Select

                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If

        End With

    Next n

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to do, the following code might fit you:

```
Sub delete_extra_Sheets()

    Dim n As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strImportFile As String
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook


    For i = 1 To 2

        strImportFile = SPATH & GETIMPORTFILE(i)


        wbTarget Workbooks.Open(strImportFile)

        If wbTarget Is Nothing Then

            For n = wbTarget.Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1

                If wbTarget.Worksheets(n).Name = "Segments" Or wbTarget.Worksheets(n).Name = "Summary" Then
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    wbTarget.Worksheets(n).Delete
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                End If
            End If

            wbTarget.Close True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Here i will loop through all the workbooks you have (this case 2 as per GERTIMPORT procedure).

Then, I'm looping thorugh every Sheet in the Workbooks and using n (index) to find the name and compare it to Segments amd Summary. If true, I will delete them.

Try that